# Android Studio: debug classes depending on a flavour

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-billing

I have an application with three different flavours and two build types. The main module defines some common interfaces and each flavour implements them. The **flavours correspond to stores** : google, amazon and samsung. The app proposes some **in-app purchases**, which is **specific to each flavour**.

I implemented a few **debug classes to ease the integration tests** of the google the flavour. The debug classes implement the [IInAppBillingService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl)  and an alternative to the purchase dialog. Now the problem is that **some debug classes have dependencies on a flavour**. I can't switch to another flavour without having compilation errors.

I would like to keep these test classes, as they are used in integration tests. Also, they should be kept away from the release build type, to avoid any debug/testing code appearing in the released version.

My question is : **how to define classes with dependencies on a flavour, but that are not used during the building of the release version ?**

Comment: What folders are these debug classes in? I mean are they under `main` or `google`, `amazon`, and `samsung` or `androidTestGoogle`, `androidTestAmazon`, and `androidTestSamsung`?

Comment: The debug classes were kept in the debug folder (same level as main and flavours). I edited the question to post an answer (original post was 25 days old)

Comment: you should probably separate the debug classes into `debugFlavor` folders. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, you can put code and assets specific to a flavor in its own folder under `src`. For example you  can have folders such as `google`, `amazon`, and `samsung`  for each flavor. You can also create `debug` and `release` folders for classes and assets specific to each build type. This is useful if you have code only used for development but that should not go into the final release version.

You can take this a step further and create folders for any combination of build type and flavor, for example, `googleDebug` or `amazonRelease`.

For automated testing, create a `test` folder for unit tests which run locally on you development machine or an `androidTest` folder for instrumented tests run on a device or emulator. These can also be combined with build types and flavors, for example `androidTestDebug`,  `androidTestSamsung`, or `androidTestSamsungDebug`.

All classes for testing should go under

Comment: Thanks ! I will give it a try.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine now ! Just one correction to bring. The folder name should be googleDebug, as stated here : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

Comment: @Gordak I was afraid that I had it backwards. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the classes that handles the billing logic in the flavour folder directly, I used another **module specific to a flavour**.

In the google billing module, I keep all the classes involved in the in-app purchases. **Each module specific to a flavour is imported for the corresponding flavour**. This way, I avoid mixing code specific to different flavours.

For example, in the build.gradle file I have :

> googleCompile project(path: ':inappbilling_google')

In the inappbilling_google module, I have all the classes involved in in-app purchase through Google in-app billing. There is a debug folder to keep all the classes that should not appear during the release build process.

I was quite happy with this solution, as I keep clearly separate the code of the different flavours and build types... until I discovered that Gradle had some limitations. Indeed, the code present in the debug folder of modules is not included during the compilation. This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962) (limitation) of Gradle and the [Android Gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

However, the Google team and Gradle team have worked on this and have announced a [solution to this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/2-5-alpha-gradle-plugin), with the version 2.5 of the Android Gradle plugin.

In a near future, it will be possible to separate our code using the Android Gradle plugin only. Good news !

Comment: Isn't this the purpose of the flavor folders? Also, if these classes are only used for using, they should go in a `androidTestFlavor` folder.

Comment: I also use them in the debug build.